# Why are there tags for "jobs" and "job-control"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

This seems redundant to me.

The tag wiki excerpt for [jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) just says "Job control in a shell," but the full wiki is more useful and says:

> A job is a process or group of processes which is managed by a shell running in a terminal. The shell tracks which job is in the foreground, reports jobs' termination, can suspend and resume jobs, and can send signals to running jobs. This feature is known as job control.

The [job-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-control) tag has no wiki entry, but a longer usage excerpt:

> Questions about the various ways jobs can be controlled by the shell: suspending, resuming, terminating execution etc.

I don't see any reason for these to be separate tags.  If anyone disagrees with this, what should be the distinction between their uses?

Can we merge these tags?

Comment: Maybe just merging would be enough.

Comment: saving [this search](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs+-background-process+-batch-jobs+-job-control) to work through...

Comment: just for bragging points: i suggested that synonym months ago. i didn't care to make a meta post though. so maybe no one saw that synonym suggestion. http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/job-control/synonyms

Comment: @lesmana, I award you five bragging points.  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[job-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-control) is mostly used for shell job control, i.e. most questions revolve around `&`, `fg`, `bg`, `nohup`, `disown`. [jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) is used mainly for job control but also for background processes. (And occasionally for people asking for or offering work…)

I think we should go through [jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) and retag some questions that aren't about shell job control but about [background-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-process) or [batch-jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-jobs). Once this is done (but not before), merge [jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) into [job-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-control) and remove [jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs).